# Why do these two volume integrals express different values?

Tags: calculus

This is a question from a textbook I am reading:

> Find the volume when the region **R** is revolved about the y-axis
>   when **R** is defined as the region bounded by $x = \sqrt{16-y^2}$ and
>   $x = 0$.

Because the function is symmetrical about the y-axis *and* being revolved about the y-axis, why don't these two integrals evaluate to the same value?

Integral one: $$\int_0^4\!\pi\left(\sqrt{16-y^2}\right)^2\,dy = \frac{128\pi}3$$

Integral two: $$\int_{-4}^4\!\pi\left(\sqrt{16-y^2}\right)^2\,dy = \frac{256\pi}3$$

It seems to me that they represent the same volume--like creating a semicircular volume by revolving a fourth of a circle about its base, or by revolving a semicircle along its base.

I think that the second equation overestimates the volume because it counts the same volume twice. (The textbook says otherwise!)

Comment: The second integral is the double of the first one since it computes the first one two times.

Comment: $\displaystyle\int^a_{-a} f(t)dt = 2\int^a_0 f(t)dt$ if $f$ is even.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function is not symmetrical about the $y$-axis, indeed the curve "lives" in the first and fourth quadrants.

There is symmetry about the $x$-axis, which is why one integral is twice the other.

**Remark:** Since you are much more familiar with integration with respect to $x$, you might interchange the roles of $x$ and $y$ (geometrically: reflect in the line $y=x$). Then you will see more clearly what is going on. The first integral gives the volume of a half-sphere. The second gives the volume of a full sphere.

Comment: Thank you, when I visualized the graph I mistakenly used the usual x-y Cartesian plane as a background, forgetting to consider the format of the bounding equation.

Comment: Yes, they pulled a switch on you. Not nice!